# pgfplot error with mathematical equation

Tags: pgfplots, plot

I'm new to this site and I'm searching for the help. I'm trying to plot an adsorption isotherm described with specific equation. I used `pgfplots` package with following commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
ymin=0, ymax=100,
xmin=0, xmax=105,
]%
\addplot[violet,domain=0:100,samples=999]{((38.25708798*23.0303696*(x/41.77116184))/(1-(x/41.77116184)))*((1-(2.76389715+1)*((x/41.77116184)^2.76389715)+2.76389715*((x/41.77116184)^(2.76389715+1)))/(1+((23.0303696-1)*(x/41.77116184))-23.0303696*((x/41.77116184)^(2.76389715+1))))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which leads to the:

[image]

The plotted isotherm has an error shape, because the plotted isotherm should be:

[image]

Am I missing something, or is it a bug of the PGFPlots package?

Comment: Your equation has a divide by zero at 41.77116184.

Comment: Mathematica confirms the infinity mentioned above. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YLIdG.png)

Comment: @Nasser Well, you really only need to look at the equation and see that one divides by `1-x/41.77116184` at one point ...

Comment: Someone should post an answer :)

Comment: All true but shows up I think because of the 5 figure accuracy used by `pgfplots`: if one plots the same equation in Excel using data points every 0.01 then this does not show.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see it! I was automatically plotted with excel with lower accuracy (as Joseph Wright wrote with accuracy 0.01) and didn't check solutions for the primary equation. Once more, thank you very much.